# reorganizing database

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables that are related to each other.

The first Table is `tournaments` and has the following fields

```
tournamentId
tournamentName
tournamentStatus
tournamentBuyIn
tournamentPrizePool
tournamentStart
tournamentEnd
tournamentDuration
tournamentParticipants
```

The second table is `tourn_results` which contains the results for the above Tournament Table. It contains the following fields.

```
result_id
tournamentId
tournamentName
tournamentDate
playerId
playerName
playerRank
prizeWon
tournamentParticipants
```

I added the `tournamentName` and `tournamentDate` fields to make it easier when searching through the 1,000,000 plus records. Previously I was using the following code to pull up records.

```
SELECT r.playerName,
   SUM(CASE WHEN r.playerRank = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'FirstPlace',
   SUM(CASE WHEN r.playerRank = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/Count(*)*100 AS 'WinPercent',
   SUM(CASE WHEN r.playerRank = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) AS 'SecondPlace',
   SUM(CASE WHEN r.playerRank = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/Count(*)*100 AS 'LosePercent',
COUNT(*) AS 'TotalGames'
  FROM `tournaments` t
  LEFT
  JOIN `tourn_results` r
    ON r.tournamentId = t.tournamentId
 WHERE t.tournamentName LIKE "Royal Flush Daily"
   AND t.tournamentStart BETWEEN '2015-06-08 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-08 23:59:59'
   AND (r.playerRank = 1 OR r.playerRank = 2)
 GROUP
    BY r.playerName
 ORDER
    BY `FirstPlace` ASC
```

It has been working good for figuring out the results. However I want to see how many records there are for **each day** if the `tournamentName` matches my query. I figured the best way was to add the `tournamentDate and tournamentName` fields to the results database.

I need to now copy the `tournamentName` from the `tournaments` table as well as the `tournamentDate` if it's `BETWEEN '2015-06-08 00:00:00' AND '2015-06-08 23:59:59'`

I wouldn't even know how to begin.

#### SAMPLE DATA

I abbreviated tournaments as "t_" to save space
Result from `tourn_results`

```
result_id t_Id   t_Name t_Date     playerId playerName playerRank prizeWon  t_part
1109985   407452        0000-00-00 3008     hvca410    2          0.000      2
```

Should be updated with the information from the `tournaments` table

```
t_Id   t_Name            t_Start             t_End
407452 Royal Flush Daily 2015-07-16 03:02:00 2015-07-16
```

The new result should look like the following

```
result_id t_Id   t_Name            t_Date     playerId playerName playerRank prizeWon  t_part
1109985   407452 Royal Flush Daily 2015-07-16 3008     hvca410    2          0.000      2
```

Comment: Can you add sample data, current output and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fully clear what you want to accomplish, but if you just want to update the `tourn_results` table with the tournamentname and tournamentend date you can do it using the query below:

```
update tourn_results tr
join tournaments t on tr.tournamentId = t.tournamentId
set tr.tournamentName = t.tournamentName, tr.tournamentDate = t.tournamentEnd
where t.tournamentEnd BETWEEN '2015-07-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-16 23:59:59';
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f272d/6)

It does seem unnecessary to copy the name though as you can get it from the tournaments table and as for the date, wouldn't it make more sense if the date somehow was related to when the result was obtained? I'm guessing that there is some other table that might hold the dates of the matches played. Maybe that date is what you really want?

Comment: As I mentioned I am adding the columns to make it easier to search. I have 1,158,405 rows and it takes minutes to find all the results for **each day**. I don't care when it started or ended. I just want to return the results for the date I select. I think adding an index on the newly added Date Field will speed it up. 

I also added the tournamentName field because the majority of the results are "Royal Flush Daily". I figured that might increase the speed as well.

Comment: Is there anyway to trim `t.tournamentEnd` because I only want the `date` not `datetime`. Will mySQL do this automatically?

Comment: @aRrOwDreWLs If you only want the date part use and not time you can use `date(t.tournamentEnd)`, As for your performance problems, it sounds like you might be missing some indexes. It might also be worth looking into partitioning the data, or move some of it to an archive unless you need continuous access to all of it. These are different questions though.